# Why doesn't Codelite create a make file?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, codelite

I'm using Solus **Linux** with G++ and whenever I build the default console project in **CodeLite** I get the following output

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f Makefile'
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/make: No such file or directory
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

I checked and **make does not exist in /usr/bin** in-fact, the most promising thing I found in this directory was a file called **codelite-make**

Here are the options I selected at project creation

Category: Console
Type: Simple executable (g++)
Compiler: GCC
Debugger: GNU gdb debugger
Build System: CodeLite Make Generator

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @drescherjm I did check and make is not in the directory "/usr/bin/" my question is why hasn't codelite created this file?

Comment: `/usr/bin/make` is soemthing you install via your package manager for your OS. codelite should not provide it.

Comment: @drescherjm **sudo eopkg install make** seems to have fixed the issue, now I'm getting an error stating that stdio.h can't be found, but I know how to solve this. Can you add your amazingly simple comment as an answer, so that I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: You seem to be missing `glibc` for the new problem.

Comment: @drescherjm The solution to the second problem is similar to the first. I just had to run **sudo eopkg it -c system.devel** which is similar to installing **build-essientials** on ubuntu and everything was found.

Comment: You may need gdb and / or gcc also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your package manager for your `linux` OS to install `make` and now `glibc` and possibly other parts of your toolchain. `CodeLite` does not provide these.

Comment: I don't know if mentioning the equivalence of ubuntu's build-essentials is a good edit (even though ubuntu has become the most popular linux distro). I have never used ubuntu for software development however I can guess what it means. You assume everyone has ubuntu development experience first.